# TypeError: unexpected keyword argument: img_num

Tags: python, image-processing, 3d, tiff, scikit-image

I have several 2D images, and want to convert these slices to a 3D image with python. i found the next code, and I don't not know what exactly I have done worng...

```
from skimage import io
im_collection = io.imread_collection('C:/Users/Itzik/Desktop/images/*.tiff')
im_3d = im_collection.concatenate()
```

This is the error message that I got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

~\anaconda3\envs\Segmentation 3D\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\collection.py in concatenate_images(ic)
     45         ar = np.concatenate(all_images)
     46     except ValueError:
---> 47         raise ValueError('Image dimensions must agree.')
     48     return ar
     49 

~\anaconda3\envs\Segmentation 3D\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\collection.py in <listcomp>(.0)
      45         ar = np.concatenate(all_images)
      46     except ValueError:
 ---> 47         raise ValueError('Image dimensions must agree.')
      48     return ar
      49

~\anaconda3\envs\Segmentation 3D\lib\site-packages\tifffile\tifffile.py in __init__(self, arg, name, 
offset, size, multifile, _useframes, **kwargs)
   2179                         setattr(self, key, bool(value))
   2180                 else:
-> 2181                     raise TypeError(f'unexpected keyword argument: {key}')
   2182 
   2183         fh = FileHandle(arg, mode='rb', name=name, offset=offset, size=size)

TypeError: unexpected keyword argument: img_num
```

Comment: strange... Could you create an issue in https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues, including both the version of scikit-image you're using and minimal example data to reproduce the error? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, thank you for helping, I changed the version to 0.14 and it's working preety well!

Comment: Well, ideally we'd love to help you so you can use the latest version, but as long as you're happy! =)

Answer (score 1):

We finally figured this out on the [scikit-image issue tracker](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/4979). The fix is to specify the tifffile plugin:

```py
from skimage import io
im_collection = io.imread_collection(
    'C:/Users/Itzik/Desktop/images/*.tiff', plugin='tifffile'
)
im_3d = im_collection.concatenate()
```